# Cannot detect strikeout data from excel using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, strikethrough

I am using Java 8, excel and apache poi for my project. There are certain cell values that I am interested in extracting from excel using java. I am trying to detect text which is strikeout in the excel cells, but the format of text is little different that is why I am facing some problems.

Below is how data laid out in my excel sheet:

[image]
[image]

After extacting this data from excel, I always save it in string arraylist format like this `a = [text 1, text 2, text 3]`. code is mentioned below if you want to see how I am storing data in this arraylist.

**What I want:**

I want to ignore all those texts which are strikeout, so in above case I expect to have output like this `[text 2, text 3]` for first picture and second picture.

**What I tried:**

For the sake of just detecting strikeout values, I tried below code first:

```
XSSFRichTextString text = new XSSFRichTextString(a.get(0));                             
XSSFFont font = text.getFontAtIndex(0);
Boolean font_striked = font.getStrikeout();
```

but above code is not working as `font_striked` returns `null`, it must return true or false

The code which partially works in my case on single line cell values is:

`boolean striked_out = sheet.getRow(row_index).getCell(column_index).getCellStyle().
getFont().getStrikeout();`

This code only works if there is single line value in the cell and **not** with bullet list as shown above. It fails as it is not made for such kind of text.

**P.S**
I believe that if somehow I am able to detect even a single strikeout string in bullet points from arraylist, I can make it work for all the data.

As per the answer below I have updated my question adding following code to show how I make my string arraylist

How I convert data in excel into Arraylist:

```
String value_header = cell.getStringCellValue();
String[] newline_split = value_header.split("-");

for (int i = 0; i < newline_split.length; i++){
            final_values = newline_split[i].
                  replace("\n"," ").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();
            XSSFRichTextString text = new XSSFRichTextString(final_values);                     
            XSSFFont font = text.getFontAtIndex(0);
            Boolean font_striked = font.getStrikeout();
} // for ends here
```

Comment: "I always save it in an arraylist format " How? Show code please. And what kind of `ArrayList`? `ArrayList<String>`? If so, then all formats will be lost since `String` does not have some formats. So `new XSSFRichTextString(a.get(0))` will be a `XSSFRichTextString` without formats.

Comment: @AxelRichter as you asked, I have update my code in P.S section, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the `RichTextString` first, then go through all `FormattingRun`s, check whether it is stroked out and only if not, then get the appropriated substring and put it into the `List`:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class ReadExcelRichTextCells {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelRichTextCells.xlsx"));

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {

    switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
     case STRING:
      XSSFRichTextString richtextstring = (XSSFRichTextString)cell.getRichStringCellValue();
      String textstring = richtextstring.getString();

      List<String> textparts = new ArrayList<String>();

      if (richtextstring.hasFormatting()) {
       for (int i = 0; i < richtextstring.numFormattingRuns(); i++) {

        if (richtextstring.getFontOfFormattingRun(i)==null || !richtextstring.getFontOfFormattingRun(i).getStrikeout()) {

         int indexofformattingrun = richtextstring.getIndexOfFormattingRun(i);
         String textpart = textstring.substring(indexofformattingrun, 
                                                indexofformattingrun + richtextstring.getLengthOfFormattingRun(i));
         String[] textpart_split = textpart.split("-");
         for (int j = 0; j < textpart_split.length; j++){
          String text = textpart_split[j].replace("\n", "").trim();       
          if (!"".equals(text)) textparts.add(text);
         }
        }
       } 
      } else {
       textparts.add(textstring);
      }

      System.out.println(textparts);
      break;

     //...
     default:
      System.out.println("default cell"); //should never occur
    }
   }
  }

  wb.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it works like a charm, only problem is if i put stroked out text on 2nd position in excel cell, it returns null exception. In my excel file i have strikeout text at different positions. I am trying to solve that error but yes this code works perfectly fine.

Comment: See code after edit. The [XSSFRichTextString.getFontOfFormattingRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRichTextString.html#getFontOfFormattingRun-int-) can be null if no formatting is applied to the specified text run. That must be taken into account.

Comment: Okay. I have updated my question and added one more picture of excel cell. Your code is working fine in first case, but in case of second picture it only shows `text 3` as output and not `text 2, text 3`. I am trying to find a workaround regarding this and then it will be completely solved.

Comment: See new edited code. A `FormattingRun` is not stroked out if either there is not a font at all for this `FormattingRun` **or** there is a font but not a font with strike out attribute.

Comment: Okay, i also made it `richtextstring.getFontOfFormattingRun(i)==null` just like your newly edited answer but i forgot to add `||` condition afterward. I was still using `&&` and it threw null exception again. but now its solved. thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get the strikethrough in Excel with `VBA`:

```
Public Sub IsMyActivecellStriked()
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Font.Strikethrough
End Sub
```

If you have something like this:

[image]

Then the you should find a way to access the characters and check for them. Like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strRange    As String
    Dim varArr      As Variant
    Dim varStr      As Variant
    Dim lngStart    As Long
    Dim lngEnd      As Long

    strRange = [a1]
    varArr = Split(strRange, Chr(10))

    For Each varStr In varArr
       lngStart = InStr(1, strRange, varStr)
       Debug.Print [a1].Characters(Start:=lngStart, Length:=Len(varStr)).Font.Strikethrough
       Debug.Print [a1].Characters(Start:=lngStart, Length:=Len(varStr)).Text
    Next varStr

End Sub
```

This will give you the following in the immediate window:

```
False
aaa
True
bbb
True
ccc
False
ddd
```

This should be possible to be translated into Java with the POI library.

Comment: vityata: How can I use this VBA script with my java code, I use apache poi library. is there any way i can use this script alongside my code?

Comment: @DhruvJ - try with `font.Strikethrough` instead of `font.getStrikeout();`

Comment: vityata: `XSSFFont` supports no such method like `font.Strikethrough`. I am still trying dig in of how to make use of your vba script with apache poi, but not there yet.

Comment: @DhruvJ - ok, I did not know that. In general, it is probably a good idea to split the value of the cells by empty space and check for each one whether it is striked through.

Comment: I split the values already and stored them in string arraylist. I also have mentioned that code above in P.S section, but there only i am stuck because I have no idea how to detect strikeout for those individual values.

Comment: @DhruvJ - I understand your issue now. Try to access characters and loop through them. Then it is easy. Take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Your solution is great and had i been programming in VBA i could have easily used it, but it seems to translate it to java is little complicated. However, the answer that AxelRichter gave is fitting best to my needs so far. I am still doing some changes with it, but its working great

Comment: @DhruvJ - there should be a way to refer to `Charachers` from the Java library. The library cannot be written without them. Give it a try. :)

Comment: yes i am looking into it, but i shall accept the answer given by AxelRichter above as final. it is easy to merge that code with mine, that's why.

Comment: @DhruvJ - I completely understand you, in this case it is more useful. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per I understanding above question Question (plz Correct me if I am wrong..!)
It should show whether your text in cell is strikethrough or not. ( TRUE or FALSE)

Below I have created a demo with that :

```
public class ApachePOI {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Using workbook
        XSSFWorkbook workbook;

        try {
            //Access excel file as workbook
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(new File("/testExcelfile.xlsx")));

            // first sheet of excel file
            XSSFSheet xssfFirstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            //Check for A1  cell that strikethrough or not
            boolean strikedOutTextStatus = xssfFirstSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFont().getStrikeout();

            //print status of A1 cell text
            System.out.println(strikedOutTextStatus);
```

// UPDATED CODE

```
      if(strikedOutTextStatus){

            String cellStringValue = xssfFirstSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();

            System.out.println("cell Value  : "+cellStringValue.replace("-", "").replace(" ", ""));
        }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }    
}
```

Comment: what you understood is right, but in your code `boolean strikedOutTextStatus = xssfFirstSheet.getRow(0).getCell(0).getCellStyle().getFont().getStrikeout();` will only detect true or false if there is only one cell value. If there are multiple values with newlines or brackets and such it will fail to detect that. try to run this method on the excel value shown in image above in my question, you will get what i mean. I tried your solution earlier as i mentioned that in my P.S section of question, but its not working on given excel data.

Comment: Edited approach : As I have added in above demo, Steps:  1. first check whether text in cell is strikethrough. ( It will give TRUE ot FALSE) 2. Then extract value from cell and then do whatever you want to do with that.(You may trim it or add to another list)

Comment: @vivh - the OPs problem is that there are different formats in the same cell. E.g. there is both strikethrough and non strikethrough in the same cell.

Comment: @Vityata - I was thinking that those texts are in different cells. Thanks for clarification.Now I got it exactly.

Comment: @vivh yes, i thought so :) if you look at the picture you'll realize that those bullet texts are in same cell. Just to occupy less space i did not cropped image in a way that it shows labels also along with it.